# Tricky Limits Problem ()

Tags: limits

**Problem**:
If $\lim_{x \to 0}{\sin2x\over x^3}+a+{b\over x^2}=0$ then find the value of $3a+b$.

**My attempt**: $\lim_{x \to 0}{\sin2x\over x^3}+a+{b\over x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\sin2x\over 2x}({2\over x^2})+a+{b\over x^2}={2+b+ax^2\over x^2}$.From this we can conclude that $a=0$ and $b=-2$, hence $3a+b=-2$. However the answer is $2$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what you did is not correct.

Comment: you replaced $\frac{sin(2x)}{2x}$ by 1, which is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have
$sin(X)=X-\frac{X^3}{6}+X^3\epsilon(X)$
with $\displaystyle{  \lim_{X\to 0}  \epsilon(X)=0}$.

thus

$sin(2x)=2x-\frac{4x^3}{3}+x^3\epsilon(x)$.

so

$\frac{sin(2x)}{x^3}+a+\frac{b}{x^2}$

$=\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{4}{3}+a+\frac{b}{x^2}+\epsilon(x)$.

the limit is $0$ if

$a=\frac{4}{3}$ and $b=-2$.

finally

we will have
$3a+b=2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please spot the error in my reasoning.

Comment: we can't replace a function by its limit.

Answer (score 2):

We have that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} + a + \frac{b}{x^2} 
& = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ a + \frac{\sin 2x + bx}{x^3} \\
& = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ a + \frac{2 \cos 2x + b}{3x^2},
\end{align}
which gives that $b=-2$, otherwise the second term blows up. Continuing,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ a + \frac{2 \cos 2x -2 }{3x^2}
& = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ a + \frac{-4 \sin 2x}{6x} \\
& = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ a + \frac{-8 \cos 2x}{6} \\
& = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ a - \frac{8}{6}.
\end{align}
Hence $a = 8/6$ and $3a+b = 2$.

Comment: For me it is not very clear from where did you obtain in line number two $\frac{{2\cdot \cos{2x}+b}}{3x^2}$? Thanks!

Comment: From L'hopital's rule